# Keras sparse_categorical_crossentropy throws squeeze error

Tags: keras

I am attempting to convert a Keras model from regression to classification. It's a stock trading system, where I want to buy the 3 symbols out of a universe of 15 or 20 with the best predicted performance. The labels in this case will be the ranks. The documentation for `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` shows this:

```
>>>> y_true = [1, 2]
>>>> y_pred = [[0.05, 0.95, 0], [0.1, 0.8, 0.1]]
```

where 1 & 2 are some hypothetical categories & the pred values are the probabilities from a `softmax` activation. This is exactly what I want. I am quite sure I have not set up the output layer accordingly -- I've customized a training loop to see what is happening -- but I can't figure out how to set it up correctly. Here's a toy version of the program, with no real feature data.

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

## Prep data
#
start_date = "2022-01-01"
end_date = "2022-03-31"
spy = data.DataReader("SPY", "yahoo", start=start_date, end=end_date)
tlt = data.DataReader("TLT", "yahoo", start=start_date, end=end_date)

joined = spy.join(tlt, lsuffix="_SPY", rsuffix="_TLT")
joined["fwd_SPY"] = joined["Close_SPY"].shift(-5) / joined["Close_SPY"]
joined["fwd_TLT"] = joined["Close_TLT"].shift(-5) / joined["Close_TLT"]

PREDICT = ["fwd_SPY", "fwd_TLT"]

joined = joined.dropna()
# Convert performance to ranks
ranks = joined[PREDICT].rank(axis=1, ascending=False).astype(int)
for col in PREDICT:
    joined[col] = ranks[col]
print(joined.tail())

## Build/train model
#
BATCH_SIZE = 5
y = joined[PREDICT]
x = joined.drop(PREDICT, axis=1)
# Normalize features
x = (x - np.mean(x)) / np.std(x)

x_batched = tf.keras.utils.timeseries_dataset_from_array(data=x, targets=None, sequence_length=BATCH_SIZE)
x_batched_all = list(x_batched.as_numpy_iterator())[0] 
print(x_batched_all.shape)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(x_batched_all[0].shape)))
model.add(layers.Dense(32))
model.add(layers.Dense(y.shape[-1], activation="softmax"))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=["sparse_categorical_accuracy"],
              optimizer="adam")

model.fit(x_batched_all, np.expand_dims(y.iloc[BATCH_SIZE-1:].to_numpy(), -1), verbose=1)
```

Note that the `np.expand_dims` call is based on other similar questions, but it does not have an impact.